# Error type hinting tuple (Vs code Microsoft Python extension)

Tags: python, generator, vscode-extensions, type-hinting

I like annotating my code and keeping the python extensions type checks in semi-strict mode. I often use generators to create tuples and with variable length tuples I had no problem but I just noticed that when I write something like:

```
my_tup : tuple[int, int, int] = tuple(i for i in range(3))
```

The Python extension by Microsoft for Vs code complains because I'm assigning a tuple of variable length to a tuple of length 3.
Now it's clear to me that the expression `tuple(generator...)` in this case will **always** return a tuple of length 3, am I correct and the extension is just not smart enough or did I not understand generators correctly?

Comment: yeah most static analysis won't be able to infer the size of the result on the right.

Comment: note, that extensions uses `pyright` for type checking, but I can't actually reproduce the error with pyright locally, even if it is actually wrong (e.g. I use `range(10)`, so actually, it's probably good that you are getting a warning, you can always just ignore this line)

Comment: I'm also using Pylance, @juanpa.arrivillaga can you reproduce with that?